# Decide the characteristics of the points of the function $f(x,y,z)=4xyz-x^4-y^4-z^4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

So I want to answer the question:

"The function

$$f(x,y,z)=4xyz-x^4-y^4-z^4$$

have stationary points in $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$. Decide the characteristics of the points."

I already know the stationary points, which helps as I don't need to calculate them. But I want to decide if they are, to say, positive definite, negative definite etc. And also if they have like a saddle point.

My take on it as that I need to calculate the derivatives and second derivatives as such:

$$f'_{x}=-4x^3, f'_{y}=-4y^3, f'_{z}=-4z^3,$$
$$f''_{xx}=-12x^2, f''_{yy}=-12y^2, f''_{zz}=-12z^2, f''_{xy}=4z, f''_{xz}=4y, f''_{yz}=4x.$$

But where do I go on from here? How to I come to the point when I can decide the characteristics? I feel like I should use equation systems but I have no idea on how to approach it. I should also add that I in no way should use matrixes.

Comment: @WillJagy No, I did not ask this yesterday. I see now that you gave an answer to my question yesterday, but that involved $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ and I still wanted to find out about the characteristics, as in this question. But it is a totally different question with a total different approach to a solution. There I had done the first one already. I have the exact question that is from the book up in this question. And I am pretty sure I should solve this by calculating the gradient, to then get equation systems and then write it in quadratic form.

Comment: @WillJagy I also can't find where you said "there are points arbitrarily close to the origin where the function is positive..." you only linked two sites and made a matrix approach.